# Why DialogFragment is not being destroyed while Dialog is?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

as the title says, why does Android keeps the `DialogFragment` open when a `configChange` happens while any type of `Dialog` is being destroyed as soon as there is a `configChange`? is it because the `Android` doesn't want to keep a reference to the `Context` passed to the `Dialog`? if so, then how they actually keep surviving the `DialogFragment` while `configChange` happened?

Edit : i do know that the `dialogFragment` is being recreated, why don't they do the same to `Dialogs` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after i dig-in into the source code of the `DialogFragment` i found out that its just a `Fragment` that handles `configChanges` by `savingInstance` of the current `Fragment` and re-create it on `Orientation` Changed.
When we actually call `dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),TAG)` the Framework create a `Fragment` that handles `Dialog` `lifeCycle` for example

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mStyle = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_STYLE, STYLE_NORMAL);
        mTheme = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_THEME, 0);
        mCancelable = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_CANCELABLE, true);
        mShowsDialog = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SHOWS_DIALOG, mShowsDialog);
        mBackStackId = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_BACK_STACK_ID, -1);
    }
}
```

in `onCreate` method it restores the `Dialog` parameters that are saved within

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

and restore the `dialog` instance in
 `@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}`
by calling `mDialog.onRestoreInstanceState(dialogState);`

so when we actually use `DialogFragment` the `Framework` save us the time by handling the `configChanges` that might occur while `Dialogs` are showing.

Answer (score 1):

DialogFragment is destroyed too, but then re-created.
The data provided with setArguments(Bundle) is preserved and can be used to restore the initial state of the fragment.

Comment: But, isn't the dialogfragment is actually a dialog kind of type?

Comment: k0sh: No, it is a fragment with some logic to manage a dialog.

Comment: Hmmm, let me get to my laptop later and dig into the source code to find what is really going on. Meantime thanks, +1